# JDA 5; The Specified ID is not a valid snowflake

Tags: java, intellij-idea, discord-jda

I've been trying to write a command for my small moderation bot that takes the user mentioned in the syntax, and assigns a role to them for a certain amount of time specified.

However, no matter what code I try, either my IDE yells at me, or I usually get the exact same error message. When I try code like

```
       if (args.length == 2) {
          Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(args[1].replace("<@", "").replace(">", ""));
          Role role = (Role) event.getGuild().getRolesByName("Muted", true);
```

I continuously get this error message in the console here:

```
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: The specified ID is not a valid snowflake (<@!389127045520556043>). Expecting a valid long value!
```

However, whenever I try code like

```
 if (args.length == 2) {
    Member member = (Member) event.getGuild().getMembersByName(args[1], true);
    Role role = (Role) event.getGuild().getRolesByName("Muted", true);
```

I get the error of

```
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList cannot be cast to class net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member (java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

despite my IDE telling me to cast both the Member variable and Role variable to their respective types.

I've looked around wherever I can, I've tried looking even in the JDA 5 Documentary for answers, to no avail. I literally created this stackoverflow account because I just have no idea what else to do.

Comment: The getByName getters return lists, you should use them like any other lists.

Comment: Now it's actually retrieving the member mentioned, however now it still isn't following through on the rest of the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is going to take a little explaining into the way JDA gets it's people. In JDA 5, this hasn't changed at all. But lets begin with the first line of code.

```java
       if (args.length == 2) {
          Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(args[1].replace("<@", "").replace(">", ""));
          Role role = (Role) event.getGuild().getRolesByName("Muted", true);
```

From what I can see, you're getting the member by pulling the mention as a string, and from that using the ID. However, JDA has a built in method that does this for you, also known as [`Message#getMentionedMembers();`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#getMentionedMembers%28%29). (This is more stable, as it does not depend on getting the Id from the message in the mention. And in some cases, mentions will also contain a ! at the beginning).

To fix this, you can use this code:

```java
List<Member> members = event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers();
List<Role> roles = event.getGuild().getRolesByName("Muted", true);
if (members.size() != 1) {return;} // Or add code here to handle the mistake, this will depend on how you're handeling commands
if (roles.size() != 1) {return;} // Might wanna add a handler in here, or store the ID of the role in a database/file. This will return if either there are no roles, or if there are more then 1 role called muted)

Member member = members.get(0); // We get the single member in the list, since we made it so we can only have 1 member
Role role = roles.get(0); // Same for the role

event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(member, role).queue();
// The rest of your code, this can be logging the moderation. Or doing other stuff like doing it on other guilds.
```

To explain the issue in the second line of code:

```java
 if (args.length == 2) {
    Member member = (Member) event.getGuild().getMembersByName(args[1], true);
    Role role = (Role) event.getGuild().getRolesByName("Muted", true);
```

You are trying to get a member object, and casting it to a member object for something that is a list. This is something Java doesn't like, so it throws a NPE. The code above fixes this, by not casting anything, but rather getting the item in the list for both. As you're requesting "getRole`s`ByName" and "getMember`s`ByName".

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your explanations for this. I've been using a couple year old tutorials and working off of those for a little bit, it's been incredibly difficult to parse through what worked then and what worked now.

Comment: I suggest joining the JDA Discord if you have more questions, as most people here can help you get up to date with the issues you're facing. But also why something might or might not work. An invite for that is here: https://discord.gg/jda

Comment: If this helped you solve your issue, please click on the green checkmark to mark this as the solution. This helps other people find the cause of their issue